# Add a geojson file in Android error (Surround with try/catch)

Tags: android, google-maps, geojson

I try to import a geojson to my Google map Android app. But I have the following error in code.

> The Code for adding geojson:

```java
GeoJsonLayer layer = new GeoJsonLayer(mMap, R.raw.nbg_bank ,
                getApplicationContext());

layer.addLayerToMap();
```

> and the error:unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Is the solution to do a try/catch?

When I do try/catch the code change to without any error but I can't see the pointss in the map's app:

```java
    GeoJsonLayer layer = null;
            try {
                layer = new GeoJsonLayer(mMap, R.raw.nbg_bank ,
                        getApplicationContext());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            layer.addLayerToMap();
```

[image]

Comment: Have you checked if there is any exception in logcat,which is eventually being caught in one of the catch blocks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: the try/catch solution it is ok. The problem was the coordinate system. I use WGS84 but the EPSG:4326 is the correct not the epsg:3857 crs that I used.